# Remove all spaces in lines but not between double quotes

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

### Example:

input =

```
This is an example text with    some      spaces. 
This should be 2nd line.
However the spaces between "quotes    should not    change".
last line.
```

output =

```
Thisisanexampletextwithsomespaces. 
Thisshouldbe2ndline.
Howeverthespacesbetween"quotes    should not    change".
lastline.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\""}
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next}
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$i)} 
    1
'
```

```
Thisisanexampletextwithsomespaces.
Thisshouldbe2ndline.
Howeverthespacesbetween"quotes    should not    change".
lastline.
```

Answer (score 3):

Example with GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed -r 's/(\".*\")|\s*/\1/g' file
Thisisanexampletextwithsomespaces.
Thisshouldbe2ndline.
Howeverthespacesbetween"quotes    should not    change".
lastline.
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done using perl:

```
perl -pe 's{^\s*\n$}{}; s/ +(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*$)//g' file
```

This will delete all the blank line or lines with just 0 or more spaces and trim spaces when not between double quotes.

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/xizPNI